# $X = [ 0,\omega_1 )$ is maximal countably compact

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

(a) : why $X = [ 0,\omega_1 )$ is a first countable space? ($\omega_1$ is the first uncountable ordinal number.)

(b) : is $X = [ 0,\omega_1 )$ maximal countably compact?

Comment: Hello ! Would you, please, tell us how this question is related to *Mathematica* ? Code you are working on ? Examples ?

Comment: Welcome to Math.se! You should create an account so you can comment when people provide answers, if you want a clarification. It is also recommended that you provide some information about how much/what you have tried so people that answer can know at what level they should provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

HINTS:

(a) For $\alpha\in[0,\omega_1)$ let $\mathscr{B}(\alpha)=\{(\xi,\alpha]:\xi<\alpha\}$; show that $\mathscr{B}(\alpha)$ is a countable local base at $\alpha$.

(b) It’s well-known that $X$ is countably compact. Since $X$ is $T_1$, it suffices to show that every infinite subset of $X$ has a limit point, which is not hard to do: if $A\subseteq X$ is infinite, recursively construct a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $A$, and show that $\sup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_n$ is a limit point of $A$. Now let $\tau$ be the order topology on $X$, and let $\tau'$ be a strictly larger topology on $X$: $\tau\subsetneqq\tau'$. Let $U\in\tau'\setminus\tau$. Since $U\notin\tau$, there is some $\alpha\in U\setminus\operatorname{int}_\tau U$. This means that for every $\xi<\alpha$, $(\xi,\alpha]\nsubseteq U$.

- Show that $\alpha$ must be a limit ordinal.
- Show that there is a strictly increasing sequence $\langle\alpha_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ such that $\sup_{n\in\omega}\alpha_n=\alpha$ and $\alpha_n\notin U$ for each $n\in\omega$.
- Conclude that $\{\alpha_n:n\in\omega\}$ is a closed, discrete set in $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ and hence that $\langle X,\tau'\rangle$ is not countably compact.